# AngularJs E2E how to test if an element exists in DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, integration-testing, functional-testing

In my angular e2e test I would like to be able to tell if an element exists on the DOM, it's not an test expectation, just a condition I need.

I tried to do

```
 element(".logout-button:visible").count() > 0
```

but `count()` returns a future and won't work outside an `expect()`. It seems that there is no way to add a callback when it resolves.

I tried to do

```
element(".logout-button:visible").query(element, callback)
```

But this one throws an exception when the element does not exist without bothering to go into my callback function. So how should I achieve this rather simple task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as Angular scenario contains Jquery, you should be able to check for a specific condition using jQuery.

```
if($('#some-element:visible').length){
    //do something
}
```

Alternatively, you could sleep() the test until you know the condition is met. For example:

```
element('#some-button').click();
sleep(10);
expect(element('#new-element:visibile').count()).toBe(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll give jquery a try but I'm not quite sure if it will work because I am not sure if it works with angular's rendering cycle. That leads to your second alternative which is using a sleep(), which is something that we'd like to avoid. It slows down the application and introduce some randomness (because you never know how long is long enough for the wait).